# Using Global Function in Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am making Titanium mobile project where I want to make one global function which I can use throughout the application. For that I have created other .JS file where I have defined the function and I am including that .JS file where I need to use this function and I am successfully able to call the function.

But My question is :

Can I create new Window in that function? As I have added one Label and one MapView in that window but it is not showing, while at the start of function I have added `alert('FunctionCalled')`, it is showing me alert but not showing me the label I have added in the window.

So anybody can help me to find out whether we can open window through function. If yes then any sample example, so that I can find out what mistake I am making.

Thanks,

Rakesh Gondaliya

Comment: please show as much relevant code as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you approach CAN work but is not a best practice, you should create a global namespace, add the function to that namespace and then only include the file with the function once in app.js

```
// apps.js
var myApp = {};
Ti.include('global.js','ui.js');

myApp.ui.openMainWindow();
```

then we create a seperate file for our ui functions

```
//ui.js
(function(){

var ui = {};

ui.openMainWindow = function() {
    // do open window stuff

    // call global function
    myApp.global.globalFunction1();
}

myApp.ui = ui;
})();
```

here is where we create our global functions, we will not have to include the file everywhere since we are adding it to our global namespace

```
//global.js
(function(){

var global = {};

global.globalFunction1 = function() {
    // do super global stuff
}

myApp.global = global;
})();
```

this is a simple outline of how it can be implemented, I have a [complete code listing](http://bit.ly/kFN54W) on [my blog](http://bit.ly/juu0uR)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can create a new window or add a label or anything else. If you wanted to add a label to the current window then you would do:

```
var helloWorld = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text: "Hello World", height: "auto", width: 200 });
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(helloWorld);
```

It won't matter where the code is executing because Ti.UI.currentWindow will be the active window regardless.